# ib_logfile0 size 44895232 is not a multiple of innodb_page_size after Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I was upgrading Ubunto from 18 to 20, and lost SSH during mysql upgrade.

Mysql won't start now. It has the error:

```
ib_logfile0 size 44895232 is not a multiple of innodb_page_size after Ubuntu upgrade
```

[InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size](https://serverfault.com/questions/104014/innodb-error-log-file-ib-logfile0-is-of-different-size) I tried the suggestion here to no avail.

```
2022-07-25T17:25:13.890483Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012962] [InnoDB] Log file ./ib_logfile0 size 44895232 is not a multiple of innodb_page_size
2022-07-25T17:25:13.890544Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2022-07-25T17:25:14.375381Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2022-07-25T17:25:14.375568Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-07-25T17:25:14.375652Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
```

Almost all posts I found have the same suggestion, so I am lost.

1. deleted the 2 log files
2. set my innodb settings as found in another post (see below)

   ```
    innodb_fast_shutdown =0
    innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2560M
    innodb_log_file_size    = 256M
    innodb_log_buffer_size  = 8M
    innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 2
    innodb_thread_concurrency   = 16
    innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
   ```

Comment: innodb_page_size=8K
if I add this line I get a different error: Data file './ibdata1' uses page size 16384, but the innodb_page_size start-up parameter is 8192

Comment: Which MySQL version before the upgrade?  What version after?

Comment: It is an odd multiple of 1024 -- which should never happen.  Hence 8192 did not work.

Comment: Questions like this are better served at dba.stackexchange.com .

Comment: mysql version 5.7 to 8, thanks @rick-james I will repost there

Answer (score 3):

innodb_page_size is by default 16K which is 16384
and your innodb_log_file_size seems to be corrupted in half way during upgrade.
When you say you lost ssh, does that mean server was rebooted?
you might need to take a backup of ib_logfile0 and move out of data directory and try starting mysql with innodb_page_size as default.
Your data dictionary is already created with 16k page size so it wont accept new value.

Remove innodb_page_size variable from conf and let it be default.
Backup ib_logfile0 and move it out of data directory. When you will start mysql it will generate a new one.
Post if any more errors.

Comment: I tried the responses. Removing the innodb_page_size brought back the Log file ./ib_logfile0 size 1024 is not a multiple of innodb_page_size error. (i removed the 2 log files from the directory also)

Comment: before your error was
Log file ./ib_logfile0 size 44895232 is not
and now it is ib_logfile0 size 1024
so somewhere in my.cnf you have defined incorrect innodb_log_file_size.
you might need to remove and let it be default if you dont want to extend it.

What version of mysql you are using? Can you post the whole my.cnf?

Comment: Yunus, thank you so much for the feedback, I am sure with your help I would have got it. I had a month old backup, I restored it, because following too many tutorials I had no idea what I did and where.

Comment: Good to know you were able to solve with your old backup